# R read from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r

Trying to read a table from SQL Server. I have:

> > con
>    TDBFG\BRITTG2@CRSDPRSCG1TBV
>     Database: vision
>     Microsoft SQL Server Version: 11.00.6248

and

> >dbListTables(con)
>
> ...
>
> [5] "Province"
>
> ...

but

```
p = dbReadTable(con, "ref.Province") # in the ref schema
```

yields

```
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "ref.Province"'
```

`nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'ref.Province'`.

Problem seems to be that the table name is quoted.  How to be sure that R doesn't quote the table name in the select statement?

Comment: `dbReadTable(con, SQL("ref.Province"))` should work. But it looks like the handling of schemas in DBI is a work in progress, for instance see the discussion [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/issues/24).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `RODBC`? I have had fantastic luck.

Something like:

```
ch <- odbcConnect("DATABASE", uid = "username", pwd = "password")

query <- paste("SELECT * FROM DATABASE.dbo.TABLE", sep = "")

# Perhaps in your case:

query <- paste("SELECT * FROM DATABASE.ref.Province", sep = "")

result <- sqlQuery(ch, query, stringsAsFactor = F) # Unless you want factors..
```

Note that `result` is returned as a `data.frame`

Unfortunately I don't have any experience with `nanodbc`, but I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=Server_Name\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Yo;Uid=; Pwd=; trusted_connection=yes")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from MyTable;"))
odbcClose(channel)
```